# Saving data in a string

Tags: c#, .net, types, binary

Is it possible to store some kind of custom binary data in a string object?

For example, I have the string `"Hello!"`, which represents a sequence of bytes.

Can I store an additional byte on that string that will be meaningful only to me?

For example, an extra byte that represents the string's length.

Is there a way to tell the .NET's decoder (which decodes these bytes) to *ignore* these custom bytes?

Comment: For the specific case of the length, `String` objects provide it already, so I don't see the need to store it in a "hidden byte". But in general, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to save a "*footprint*" of an original string, so I can retrieve it back from a later manipulated string. This exercise is just for fun, though

Comment: @MatiCicero strings are immutable, you can't "manipulate" them.

Comment: I guess that explains everything then.. Is there a sorry face?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't go about it that way.  How about creating a class that does what you want:

```
public class myString
{
  public string stringValue;
  public byte someSpecialByte;
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return stringValue;
  }
}
```

Then you can store whatever information you want in the class.

```
myString s = new myString();
s.stringValue = "Hello!"
s.someSpecialByte = 0;
```

**Edit** (In response to the constructor comment):

Add this to the class:

```
public myString(){} //default constructor
public myString(string sValue, byte specialByte)
{
  stringValue = sValue;
  someSpecialByte = specialByte;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest.

Comment: I would include a constructor that takes the string value and the byte value.

Comment: The coding convention in C# is to use PascalCase for Class names.